# Designing Javascript frontend <-> C++ backend communication

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, frontend, backend

In my nearest future I will have to make a system with C++ backend and web frontend (requirements). At the moment, I don't know much more about it. I think that Frontend will be triggering data delivery, not backend - so no need for Comet-like things.

Because of possibly little experience in this field, I'd really appreciate your comments about design decisions I made.

First of all, I don't like the option of generating HTML from C++. 
So, C++ backend will have to communicate with Javascript frontend. Simplest option I see here is Ajax. I think it should be ok, so far.

Commucating through Ajax with C++ backend means that backend should be capable of handling HTTP. It'd be nice to separate backend which provides actual data from HTTP handling functionality.

Here I see the place for Node.js. I got an overview of it and this's the place where all my doubts lie.

To have a HTTP handling server on Node.js, which will have the 'data backend' as a Node.js module? I think, it should be ok - but I'm not sure that I really need all this asynchronization, so there may be some simpler options I'm not aware of? How would you make such a system?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at Backbone.js for your front end. http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"All this asynchronization" is not something that Node.js works very hard to provide as an extra. It is a different view of Web serving that is easy as breathing once you understand how Node.js works.

For example, my colleagues needed a way to wrap a C++ program as a web service, but the program had a significant start-up cost, so they wanted to run just one instance of the program, running in a loop, serving all the web requests. The whole thing in Node.js took less than two screenfuls.

Wrapping a single program that is called for each request can be done in less than ten lines of Node.js. Don't think of asynchronicity as a chore - if you embrace it, Node.js is awesome.

That said, you could go the CGI route, and do it in a bit more standard way, and the end result would be pretty much the same. [This](http://rudeserver.com/) may or may not come in handy.

Comment: I like what I know now about node.js. Thanks for the answer. Probably I'll go this way. As for CGI, I think it's better to have HTTP code in higher lever javascript under node, than in CGI C++.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider CGI/FCGI module option with nginx, Apache, etc. ?

If not then I think it makes sense to start from it. Your module will handle data/json request and the rest will be handled by HTTP server.

Comment: Thanks, now I had an overview of nginx modules. In this situation, "module under nginx" looks preety much the same for me as "module under node.js" plus module on node.js will be written in higher lever language, which's an advantage. Why do you think nginx option is better?