# C++ on the back end of web app

Tags: c++, mysql, angularjs

I have been searching the web for this information and I think I need some help with understanding this better.

I would like to learn how to write back-end of a web application in **C++** and essentially how to output C++ to web pages and make it talk to a **MySQL database**. For the record I can write decent code in C++ but I never did it for web.

Wherever I go on the web and find people asking about this the first list of responses is WHY would you when yo have scripting languages. I am aware of the scripting languages, I have used them for years but I am running across cases where this is a requirement and I would like to learn more about it.

My intent it to write an app that uses **Angularjs on the front and C++ on the back**. I am a fairly well versed PHP developer and I might take this task on by writing PHP initially but I do need to account for a possibility of rewriting in C++ and this makes me think I should probably write it in C++ from the get go.

I understand that the most usual question is WHY I would use C++ instead of a scripting language so I will try and give a limited set of reasons. Please do understand I am not a pro in this aspect of C++ yet and I am evaluating the situation I am in.

So here are some of my reasons...

1. The project I am about to take on is bound to be very resource intensive and I would really like to gain all the speed I can possibly get from the get go. The more control I have over the app process the better. Essentially I need precision, I know and love C++ and it allows me to retain the control to a great degree..
2. The group of people I am talking to in the context of the project are aware of the advantages of C++ fro the resources and speed perspective and they hold a portion of the investment bag which gives them a vote in how the project will be approached. Time IS on my side, but i want to waste as little of it as possible.
3. I am comfortable with C++, have a C++ oriented mind and would love to use it in this context as much as possible.

So I guess my questions are...

1. Is there a good tutorial that can take me from the basics to
   something intermediate?
2. How do I write a web site backend in C++?
3. How do I write C++ to work with MySQL on Linux.
4. Is there a way to do this on Linux servers?
   (I believe Facebook it doing it).

I found this http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php on http://www.compileonline.com and it is giving me hope but I need more information to know how to get there.

I am aware that I am not asking an example code based question but I often find good reference posts on Stack that answer these types of questions so I hope someone can help me. I feel a bit lost here.

Comment: So... your question is 1) how do I interact with C++ from PHP, and 2) how do I call MySQL from C++...?

Comment: 1. umm,, Do I need PHP at all to write C++ backend for a  web app? 2. Yes.

Comment: 1. no, but you talk about both "tak[ing] this task on by writing PHP" and AngularJS, so I'm guessing you want one or the other to interact with C++?  Anyway, there are some questions about the frontend/backend interaction already (e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20166968/js-frontend-c-backend-communication-different-servers)).  My main point is that you should ask more specifically for what you need help with and separate the questions.

Comment: I don't think you should have tagged php as this is entirely unrelated. Your question is essentially: "How do I build a web backend with c++". Try http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/147445/how-does-one-interface-c-with-the-web-at-google-for-example
or
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417816/how-popular-is-c-for-making-websites-web-applications

Comment: Ohm thanks, I will clarify better. I meant to say, I will take on the task using PHP for now, but I need to account for having to rewrite it later,, which makes me think I should maybe write it in C++ from the get go. I am going to check out your links, thank you.

Comment: eesh yeah writing it in php now and then re-writing it entirely into c++ seems like the most headache inducing task I could imagine. Just out of curiousity, would you mind listing in your question the sorts of things that make you want to use c++ instead of php or another scripting language?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface ?

Comment: As @MarcB pointed out CGI is what you are looking for http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_web_programming.htm

Comment: Sam D, thanks! I wish I came across this right away!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My preferred approach to building angular apps is to use the back-end pretty much strictly as a REST server.

Here are a few places that list options:

[I'm searching a cgi lib in C to build a restful web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597847/im-searching-a-cgi-lib-in-c-to-build-a-restful-web-service)

and

[How popular is C++ for making websites/web applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417816/how-popular-is-c-for-making-websites-web-applications)

and

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147445/how-does-one-interface-c-with-the-web-at-google-for-example

One option that seems to come up multiple times is http://cppcms.com/. Also http://www.webtoolkit.eu

Integrating angular will be pretty much the same as integrating with any other back-end. If you're using the back-end as a REST server you can pretty much statically serve all of the angular code.

Comment: Thank you I will do some reading and get back here. Even these initial responses are helping a great deal.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for,, using the back-end as a REST server and more or less statically serving angular. I want to dump heavy lifting, db queries,, etc.. on C++ and do all front in angular. It seems logical and feels robust. Thanks for throwing in these links. It is very helpful.